# Benchmark for m2 air and m2 pro macbook

Tags: function-comparison, benchmarking, apple-silicon

Could anyone post a Mathematica benchmark for Macbook on M2 processor? I was wondering how it compares to M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacBook Pro with Apple M2 Pro chip, 32 GB memory
[image]

Comment: nice,thanks! It looks likely improved the performance.

Comment: The M1 had 10 cores. How many cores does your M2 have?

Comment: @Ghoster - M2 Pro chip has 12-core CPU (8 performance, 4 efficiency), 19-core GPU, 16-core Neural Engine

Comment: @BobHanlon The M2 Pro is a beast indeed, but I have found that some times highly parallelized computations may lead to kernel panics and reboots (appears to be random, I haven't been able to consistently replicate it). Still it's really good!